# Is it possible to write a program that will set the computer on fire?

Tags: operating-system

Let’s assume you have administrator access, and that this is a run of mill laptop or desktop. Is it possible to write a program that will result in a fire or something equally as destructive?

EDIT:
To the ”how do you think bombs work” answer: valid answer, but I’m asking about if I have a pocket universe with just a laptop, is it possible to have a program that when run, will set the computer on fire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't impossible, but with most off the shelf goods, it is unlikely you will find a deterministic way to do it.  Groups like CSA, Underwriters, ETL, are pretty careful about what they give the stamp of approval to.

Depending upon that last time you have flown in the US, you may have heard various warnings that you are not to carry a certain brand of Samsung Phone or Apple Laptop on board; further you are not allowed to store them in your luggage, and if you drop one between the seats, to notify the attendants.

These are all precautions because the FAA has determined that these devices pose a fire risk, presumably due to over-heating.   So, if you run caffeinate -- which prevents sleeping -- and ran a heavy workload, you could induce the high enough temperatures to cause ignition.

But, heavy on the *could*.  There are a lot of defenses built into the batteries themselves to prevent this; then there are system management components in the computer to prevent this; then there are monitoring components on the CPU to prevent this.  So, whatever you do, has to line up some failure mode of all of these systems simultaneously.

Not impossible, but maybe not far from it.